# My keyboard ocassionaly start behave silly

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, desktop-computer

Maybe the problem is not in the keyboard itself but in some malicious program (virus?)

Occasionally, with some months period, when I begin to type, the output is appended with "infinite" string of the same digit, in one of such periods `2`, in the other `8`.

**Example:** I hit the <kbd>A</kbd> key, and immediately start the streak of `8`:

```
a8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
```

until I press other (or the same) key to stop it. *Sometime it stops the streak, sometime not.*

For example, if I try stop it with the key <kbd>C</kbd>, after 1 or 2 seconds it continues:

```
a8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888c88888888
```

Sometimes my keyboard even *stops working for some seconds*.

I use standard keyboard (with the cable connection to my desktop computer).
Of course, I have installed antivirus program.

Restart helps, sometimes it is even not needed - the strange behavior simply stops.

Has someone similar experience, or knows what is happening?

---

**Appendix:**

By the advice of [user3169](https://superuser.com/users/328343/user3169) I tried on-screen keyboard and it works well, whereas my physical keyboard behaves strangely, as I described.

So now I know that something happens with my keyboard or with the keyboard driver. Have you any idea what happened and how to fix it?

Comment: To rule out malware, test with another keyboard; also try other USB ports to attach it to, and remove any hub or extension cable it may connect through when testing. After you've tried those steps, please click on `edit` above and add to the original post what the result is.

Comment: @K7AAY, nice tip, but I haven't other keyboard. Yes, I may borrow one, but first I have to wait some months for that strange - and **unstable** - behavior. For example, when I began write my question, it was problem, because that strange behavior began about half hour ago, but while writing it suddenly stops. I will probably buy another one for that situations, you advice is definitely a good one.

Comment: What happens if you type using the On-Screen Keyboard (Start --> All Programs --> Accessories --> Ease of Access)?

Comment: This may be because the keyboard delay is too small or the keyboard is broken. You can connect your keyboard to other devices to test if your keyboard is broken.

Comment: @user3169 - Very good advice, thanks! Now is my keyboard OK, so I have to wait some months to use your tip.

Comment: @user3169, for a very long time my keyboard worked OK, only today it started to behave as I described, so I had an opportunity to try you advice. So, the physical keyboard behaves strangely, but On-Screen Keyboard is OK. Thank for your advice, now I know that something happens with my keyboard or with the keyboard driver.

Comment: Try tapping on the 8 key a few times (if that is the only one doing this). It really seems like a stuck or damaged key. Also, when the 8's are running, will pressing shift change it?

Comment: @user3169 — your advice about On-Scread Keyboard was very useful, when the situation in my question arose again. I found out that the problem was with my physical keyboard. Please rewrite your comment as an answer and I will vote it up.